# Preventing variables from going out of scope so they persist for another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a function that creates a bunch of local variables, then passes their addresses to a function that runs in a separate thread - something like this:

```
void MyFunction()
{
    MyClass a;
    AnotherClass b;
    ...
    FinalClass z;

    CallFunctionInNewThread(&a,&b,&c,...,&z);
}
```

Of course, these variables are destroyed when the MyFunction goes out of scope (so the function in a thread is now pointing to garbage), so this setup doesn't work. What are my options here? If I allocate the variables on the heap with 'new', I will never get a chance to delete them. If I make them smart pointers or similar, I'd have to make the threaded function accept them as smart pointers, or their reference count will not be increased so they will still get destroyed immediately. It seems like they kind of want to be member variables of a wrapper class of MyFunction, but there are a few hundred lines and tens of these things and that would just be crazy messy. Are there any other choices?

Comment: Why are you against using smart pointers?

Comment: Would declaring them as static work for you?

Comment: @Nick - I am just trying not to touch the code in CallFunctionInNewThread as it is in a library. sampson-chen - if I declare them as static then when do they get destroyed?

Comment: As always, avoid using pointers to avoid headaches. The standard `std::thread` interface takes care of copying variables that are needed by the new thread.

Comment: If you want something that Just Works, use `std::thread`/`boost::thread`. If you want to make it yourself, crack open the source code on those.

Comment: @DavidDoria space for them is allocated when your program starts, and destroyed when your program ends.

Comment: So you don't have access to CallFunctionInNewThread code? What is this thread doing while it's waiting for you to call CallFunctionInNewThread, or does this function create the thread?

Comment: @James I do have access to it, but I'd just rather not change it because I use that code in many other places. This function creates the thread and then continues, which effectively means it just goes out of scope right after it creates the thread to run the function that gets passed the addresses.

Comment: @GManNickG - I am actually using QtConcurrent::run(). Kerreck SB - I guess I could copy some of these by value.. there are a few QObject's that must be passed as pointers (Qt doesn't like it's objects to be copied), so maybe I can just store those few in the "class wrapper" idea.

Comment: @sampson-chen so is that any better than just allocating them on the heap and letting them leak? If they don't get destroyed until the program ends, it is effectively a leak, no?

Comment: why not join the thread to wait for its completion if you're concerned about scope duration?

Comment: `CallFunctionInNewThread` looks fundamentally broken to me at first glance.  How do you handle parameter lifetime in the other spots it is called?

Comment: @SamMiller I can't join because I have to get out of this function to get back to the caller to execute the GUI thread. Yakk - usually I just call this from the same block where I call app.exec() (Qt's main loop) so it keeps everything in scope. I'm afraid the details of the real case are beyond the scope of the question - I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some concept that was built for this that I was missing. It looks like there is not. Thanks for all of the input.

Comment: Basically you avoided lifetime by having the parameters have infinite lifetime.  To determine the proper lifetime, whomever cleans them up needs to know when the thread is done with them.  This requires some assistance from, or some interaction with, the thread in question.  Both of which you ruled out, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any other choices?

Simply copy (if trivial) or move/swap the data (if heavy to create) -- similar to transferring ownership from one thread to the other. Seems Thread A really does not need a reference from the description. Bonus: This removes concurrent access complexities from your program.

Comment: Ok, though very annoying with the way I have things setup now (incorrectly, clearly haha), it seems like moving the data is really the right thing to do. What do you mean by "move/swap"? Say I have MyClass* myClass = new MyClass; - how do I "move" that to the other thread?

Comment: @DavidDoria in short: use `std::thread` or `boost::thread` if possible. also noted by Kerrek SB and GManNick above in comments. your arguments (`a...z`) would often be packed into a function object or functionoid. the interface for `std::thread` is simplified by c++11 features. it *could* be as simple as passing that heap object `myClass` to your thread initialization routine, if that object held all those parameters and there were a well defined way to transfer data. (cont)

Comment: (cont) so take that function object `myClass` and call its function-call operator on Thread B, then `delete` it on Thread B or delete it on Thread A in the event of error (e.g. system refused to create a thread for you or there was a parameter error). so that ultra-basic description just means that your setup and thread routines must agree with each other. that's a really basic starting point. i don't use Qt, so i can't comment on the usability of their library for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

One little trick you can do is to pass a semaphore object into the thread function and then wait for that semaphore to be signaled.  You do need to check that the thread was created successfully.

The new thread first makes local copies of the values (or references in the case of smart pointers), then signals the semaphore and carries on.

The calling thread can then continue and drop those objects off its stack without interfering with your new thread.  It can even delete the semaphore object since it is no longer required by either thread.

It does mean that the calling thread has to wait until the thread is started and has copied its data, but that probably will be a short time.  If you are going to the effort of spawning a thread to do any work at all, then this slight delay in the parent thread ought to be acceptable.